# Problems with adding input field to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I tried to add an input field, and label to the Card (The user add Card via button). But it didn't succeed. Instead of adding these input field to the Card, it put them on the in-box list.  Can any help me to solve the problem?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/L2XqS/11)

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {

        var numberOfDiv = [100];

        with(document) {
            var newDiv = createElement('div');

            var div = getElementById('userAddedDiv').appendChild(newDiv);

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDiv; i++) {
                numberOfDiv[i] = div;
            }
        }
    });

    $(function () {

        $('#userAddedDiv').sortable({
            containment: 'document',
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            opacity: '0.70',
            connectWith: '#onHoldList',
            hoverClass: '.border'
        });

        $('#onHoldList').sortable({
            containment: 'document',
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            opacity: '0.70',
            connectWith: '#userAddedDiv',
            hoverClass: '.border'
        });
    });

});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I modified your code to set a string value, in the text field. The value comes form a dialog window.  It works fine.
Then my issue is, when I add a new card to the in-box list, and I want to set a new string value on it. It works well. But at the same time the same string value gets added to the first card. You can try to add to card, and test it. I have a Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/xMK53/4/

Jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
        // Array of Card
        var numberOfCards = [100];


            // Create a new card
            var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div');
            $('#userAddedCard').append($div);

            $('<label>Title</label>').appendTo($div);              
            $('#Getbtn').click(function () {
                $('<input/>', { "type": "text", "value": $("#customTextBox").val() }).appendTo($div);
                $('<input/>', { "type": "text", "value": $("#datepicker").val() }).appendTo($div);
            });    
            // Sort cards in array
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
                numberOfCards[i] = $div.clone(true);
            }

    });
```

Comment: There is a reason a fiddle is not allowed without code here too

Comment: Why do you have two onloads? One is enough. Also why use appendChid when you have jQuery

Comment: Try to avoid using `with (var) { ... }` blocks.

Comment: Please, describe the situation, with codes using your fiddle.

Comment: why to avoid using with (var) { ... }  ???

Comment: Avoid `with` - it is ambiguous and may have unplanned side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/62QY8/)

```
$(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div'); 
    $('<label>Title</label><br/>').appendTo($div);              
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"ctb"}).appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"date"}).appendTo($div);
    var cnt =0,$currentTarget;
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
      var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
      cnt++;  
      $newDiv.prop("id","div"+cnt);  
      $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
//      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);        
    });

    // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
    $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
        $currentTarget = $(e.target);

        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });
        return false;

    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({showWeek:true, firstDay:1});

    $("#Getbtn").on("click",function() {
      var val=$("#customTextBox").val(), 
         date=$("#datepicker").val();
      $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
      $currentTarget.find(".date").val(date);
      $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes just like that. How am I able to do this in html ? I have tried to do this, but it didn't succeed.

Comment: Hoe am I able to add a textBox in the same way?

Comment: Can I please ask Is there any way to do it in html??

Comment: If you do not want to use script, you need to go via the server. Submit the form to the server with the request to add a box.

Comment: Can you give an example, how to do this??

Comment: The reason I don't want to do it in the script is that I want to put a string value in the textbox. The value comes from another div. therefore I think that I am not able to do this, in the way you showed me to do that in the script. Can you follow me??

Comment: Of course you can. See update. Next time put all your issues in the question

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question can I please ask you for help??

Comment: I have posted my question below. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Nice. I want, when I press the button (Get Value) in dialog window, to set the values to the actual card, and not to the next card. Like in your example. Thanks :)

Comment: But if I want to, when I press the button (Get Value) in dialog window, to set the values to the actual card. Can you please provide some code ?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. This is what I am looking for. So thank you for you patience with me.

Comment: What dose this code do: $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);

Comment: It sets the ID property to div0, div1, div2 and so on to be sure the ID is unique